# different search query in sql with different string on column

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

let assume one table is having 3 row

```
id | data
----------
1  | abc
2  | def
3  | ghi
```

let us assume one string x= abcghilnm

i want to select the row which contain any matching string which contains in string x

so as in above row with id 1 and 3 will be select because it contains abc and ghi which is present in string x

i'm new bie please suggest the sql query for the given situation 
thanx..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, data
from MyTable
where 'abcghilnm' like concat('%', data, '%')
```

Comment: @khizaransari This query compares your data column with the given string, appending and pre-pending `like` wildcards to do a substring match.

Comment: i run this query `select id, data
from one
where 'abcghilmn' like '%data%'` and getting i am not getting any result...(0 rows affected) please give me exact query which i shoul enter on my sql server